# Configuration.Save on a network drive

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, configuration, app-config

I developed a Winforms application for some simple tasks. This application has an App.config file where some settings are saved. I created a tab page in the application where I can adjust the settings of the configuration file using the [Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration(v=vs.110).aspx) class. I save to the App.config using a 'Save' button in the application itself which uses the [Configuration.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134087(v=vs.110).aspx).

But I have trouble when saving to the configuration file on a network folder. Everything is fine when I save my settings to the file on a local folder (like: C:\). I mean I copied the .exe and the .config to a network folder (for example: \\folder\application.exe), and when I try to save my settings to the configuration file using [Configuration.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134087(v=vs.110).aspx) then I get the following error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an
>   unauthorized operation.

EDIT: Or can I just use StreamWriter and not Configuration?

EDIT 2:

This is the stack trace:

```
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType type, String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation, SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl, GenericAcl dacl)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateTemplateAttributes(String source, String destination)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateFileAttributes(String source, String destination)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   at ToolNameSpace.Configs.Save()
```

Comment: I used to do something like this but never seen that issue.  I had user settings and application settings in the file - but when I saved it was always to the AppData folder.  Is there a stack trace for this?

Comment: Why are you saving in the AppData folder? the .config file that I'm using is always together with the .exe, so in the network drive itself and not in AppData. That's difference between your environment and mine I think

Comment: I am facing the same problem, please let me know how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file may have been created in that location as an administrator which would make it unusable by any other non administration user.

you need to set file permissions to allow everyone like this

```
private void CreateSettingsFile(string path)
    {
        XDocument document = new XDocument();
        XElement rootElement = new XElement("settings");
        document.Add(rootElement);
        document.Save(path);
        var accessControl = File.GetAccessControl(path);
        var everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        accessControl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone,
                                                            FileSystemRights.FullControl |
                                                            FileSystemRights.Synchronize,
                                                            AccessControlType.Allow));

        manager = new XmlSettingsManager(document, () => XDocument.Load("file://" + Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, this.settingsPath)),
            x => x.Save(this.settingsPath));
        File.SetAccessControl(path, accessControl);
    }
```

Comment: XmlSettingsManager? Is this included in the .NET Framework? However, I can apply the accesscontrol I think but it doesn't change anything to the behaviour. I keep getting the error

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that you need to delete the file and let the application create it under standard credentials before you can run it up again

Comment: sorry, that was from my on custom class, the settings file can be read using XDocument.Load(...)